# Skip List C++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, skip-lists

I'm trying to implement the Skip List using this article [Skip List](http://epaperpress.com/sortsearch/download/skiplist.pdf).

Code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<ctime>
#include<limits>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class SkipList{
    private:
        class SkipNode{
            public:
                T* key; //Pointer to the key
                SkipNode** forward; //Forward nodes array
                int level; //Node level
                //SkipNode constructor
                SkipNode(T* key, int maxlvl, int lvl){
                    forward = new SkipNode*[maxlvl];
                    this->key=key;
                    level=lvl;
                }
                //Method that print key and level node
                print(){
                    cout << "(" << *key << "," << level << ") ";
                }
        };

        SkipNode *header,*NIL; //Root and End pointers
        float probability; //Level rate
        int level; //Current list level
        int MaxLevel; //Maximum list levels number

        //Function that returns a random level between 0 and MaxLevel-1
        int randomLevel(){
            int lvl = 0;
            while( (float(rand())/RAND_MAX < probability) && (lvl < MaxLevel-1) )
                lvl++;
            return lvl;
        }

    public:
        //SkipList constructor
        SkipList(float probability, int maxlvl){
            this->probability = probability;
            MaxLevel = maxlvl;
            srand(time(0));
            header=new SkipNode(NULL,MaxLevel,0); //Header initialization
            T* maxValue = new T;
            *maxValue = numeric_limits<T>::max(); //Assign max value that T can reach
            NIL = new SkipNode(maxValue,0,0); //NIL initialization  
            level=0; //First level
            for(int i=0; i<MaxLevel; i++){ //Every header forward node points to NIL
                header->forward[i]=NIL;
            }
        }

        //SkipList destructor
        ~SkipList(){
            delete header;
            delete NIL;
        }

        //Method that search for a key in the list
        SkipNode* search(T* key){
            SkipNode* cursor = header;
            //Scan the list
            for(int i=level; i>=0; i--)
                while(*(cursor->forward[i]->key) < (*key))
                    cursor=cursor->forward[i];  
            cursor=cursor->forward[0];
            if(*(cursor->key) == *key) 
                return cursor;
            return NULL;
        }

        //Method that insert a key in the list
        SkipList* insert(T* key){
            SkipNode* cursor = header;
            SkipNode* update[MaxLevel]; //Support array used for fixing pointers
            //Scan the list
            for(int i=level; i>=0; i--){
                while(*(cursor->forward[i]->key) < *(key))
                    cursor=cursor->forward[i];
                update[i]=cursor;
            }
            cursor=cursor->forward[0];
            if(*(cursor->key) == *(key)){ //Node already inserted
                return this;
            }
            int lvl = randomLevel(); //New node random level
            if(lvl > level){ //Adding missing levels
                for(int i=level+1; i<=lvl; i++)
                    update[i]=header;
                level=lvl;
            }
            SkipNode* x = new SkipNode(key,MaxLevel,lvl); //New node creation
            for(int i=0; i<=lvl; i++){ //Fixing pointers
                x->forward[i] = update[i]->forward[i];
                update[i]->forward[i] = x;
            }
            return this;
        }

        //Method that delete a key in the list
        SkipList* erase(T* key){
            SkipNode* cursor = header;
            SkipNode* update[MaxLevel]; //Support array used for fixing pointers
            //Scan the list
            for(int i=level; i>=0; i--){
                while(*(cursor->forward[i]->key) < *(key))
                    cursor=cursor->forward[i];
                update[i]=cursor;
            }
            cursor=cursor->forward[0];
            if(*(cursor->key) == *(key)){ //Deletetion of the founded key
                for(int i=0; i<=level && update[i]->forward[i] == cursor; i++){
                    update[i]->forward[i] = cursor->forward[i];
                }
                delete cursor;
                while(level>0 && header->forward[level]==NIL){
                    level=level-1;  
                }
            }
            return this;
        }

        //Method that print every key with his level
        SkipList* print(){
            SkipNode* cursor = header->forward[0];
            int i=1;
            while (cursor != NIL) {
            cursor->print();
            cursor = cursor->forward[0];
            if(i%15==0) cout << endl; i++;
            }
            cout << endl;
            return this;
        }
};

main(){
    SkipList<int>* list = new SkipList<int>(0.80, 8);
    int v[100];
    for(int i=0; i<100; i++){
        v[i]=rand()%100;
        list->insert(&v[i]);
    }
    list->print();
    cout << endl << "Deleting ";
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        int h = rand()%100;
        cout << v[h] << " ";
        list->erase(&v[h]);
    }
    cout << endl;
    list->print();
    cout << endl;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        int h = rand()%100;
        cout << v[h] << " ";
        if(list->search(&v[h]))
            cout << " is in the list" << endl;
        else
            cout << " isn't in the list" << endl; 

    }
    delete list;
}
```

It gives me Segmentation Fault on line 59 (the for-cycle on the insert), but I can't understand why. May you help me please? I will accept any other improvement that you suggest. My deadline is on two days, that's why I'm asking for help.

EDIT:
I've corrected the code with bebidek suggestions (Thanks). Now first level is 0. It seems to be working, but sometimes some nodes is not inserted correctly and the search give a bad result.

LAST EDIT:
It works, thanks to all

ONE MORE EDIT:
Added comments to code, if you have any suggestion you're welcome

Comment: Did You try debugging it?

Comment: Please explain, what is this: `NIL=new SkipNode(numeric_limits<T*>::max());` supposed to do? You create an array of pointers, pointing at some invalid value, then, on insert, you try to dereference such value, and are surprised that it roars at you (in the form of segfault), because of it?

Comment: Yes, I tried debugging it, but I couldn't understand my errors. I've corrected NIL node, it contains max value that T can assume.

Comment: You can write what was your final modification, because I found three problems in your new code, but only one of them will give you wrong answers.

Comment: I added "+1" in a for inside the insert and I take out "+1" in the search for. Now it seems working. I have only to fix-up destructors

Answer (score 0):

So, first problem is when you create NIL node:

```
NIL=new SkipNode(numeric_limits<T*>::max());
```

As argument you should use pointer to existing variable, for example:

```
T* some_name = new T;
*some_name = numeric_limits<T>::max();
NIL = new SkipNode(some_name);
```

Notice, I used `T` instead of `T*` in `numeric_limits`. Of course you have to remember about deleting this variable in destructor.

Second problem is that `level` variable in your code sometimes is inclusive (I mean level number `level` exists) as in line 61, and sometimes exclusive (level number `level` doesn't exist) as in line 71. You have to be consistent.

Third problem is in line 52. You probably mean `cursor=cursor->forward[1];`, but after loop i = 0, and `forward[0]` doesn't have any sense in your code.

EDIT:
Fourth and fifth problem is in erase function.

```
cursor->~SkipNode();
```

It won't delete your node, but only run empty destructor. Use `delete cursor;` instead.

And in loop you probably wanted to write `update[i]->forward[i] == cursor` instead of `!=`.

ONE MORE EDIT:
You haven't implemented any destructor of SkipList and also you forgot about `delete list;` at the end of main(). These two will give you a memory leak.

ANOTHER EDIT:

```
srand(time(0));
```

This line should be executed once at the beginning of main and that's all. If you execute it before each random generation, you will get the same result every time (as time(0) counts only seconds and your program can run function `randomLevel()` more than once a second).

You also forgot about rewriting `precision` variable in constructor of `SkipList`.

NEXT EDIT:
In your `insert` function you don't have level randomization. I mean, you do not have ability of inserting node of level less than level of whole skip list. It's not error which will crash your program or give wrong results, but time complexity of queries in your structure is O(n) instead of O(log n).

You should use `lvl` instead of `level` in this loop in insert function:

```
for(int i=1; i<level; i++){
    x->forward[i] = update[i]->forward[i];
    update[i]->forward[i] = x;
}
```

And also minimum result of your random function `randomLevel` should be 1 instead of 0, as you don't want node witch level=0.

Comment: Thank you, you helped me a lot. Sorry for the noob errors, but I have fever, so I'm not feeling well. I've edited the post, I'm commiting one last error, may you please me lend me a hand once more?

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem in your code is probably `NIL=new SkipNode(numeric_limits<T*>::max());`

First of all i suspect you want the `key` pointer to point to a memory address that contains the biggest possible `int` value. 
But that's not what's actually happening here. Instead the `key` pointer points to the biggest possible memory-address which is most likely not available for your process.
Also the `forward` property probably contains an array of junk pointers.

Then when the first loop in the `insert` method is executed this leads to 2 problems:

1. `while(*(cursor->forward[i]->key) < *(key))` will compare the key value to an invalid pointer
2. `cursor=cursor->forward[i];` will re-assign cursor to an invalid pointer

I would first suggest you'd change the design to let SkipNode keep a value to `T` instead of a pointer:

```
class SkipNode{
public:
  T key;
  SkipNode* forward[100];
```

This will make a lot of pointer related code unnecessary and make the code simpler so less likely to run into access violation.

Also it might be cleaner to use an actual `NULL` (or event better `nullptr`) value instead of a dummy `NIL` value to indicate the end of the list.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I prefer to use pointers so this structure can be used with inherited classes, I'm using integers only for tests.